# How to avoid the LoadBy pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, database, object-oriented-design, linq

In our codebase for a sophisticated system controlling many aspects of businesses, we have a certain *unwritten law* to not fudge around in code with complicated SQL, instead writing it into a function in the entity's class to centralize the database access, and this great pattern turned into pages and pages of

```
class Car:
    List<Car> LoadByManufacturerId(id);
    List<Car> LoadByModelId(id);
    List<Car> LoadByCountryId(id);
    List<Car> LoadByCityId(id);

    Car LoadByChassis(chassis);
    Car LoadById(id);
    Car LoadByCountryIdAndChassis(countryId, chassis);
    Car LoadByPersonIdAndIndex(personId, index);
```

As in, everytime someone needs to make a query by a new parameter, a new method is created, but that's only half the problem: Many times people don't take the time to look at the code before creating one of these (documentation is non-existant) and end up creating multiple versions of the query under the same name, duplicating code all around.

We're in a C# project, but many of the devs don't understand much LINQ beyond basic `from s in tablename where blabla select s`, so what is the best way to refactor this pattern into something not so prone to these kind of problems with the minimal friction?

Comment: How complex is code inside those methods? Are they just simple SQL (maybe with 2-3 joins) and code that materializes the entity?

Comment: Yep, *usually*. But you'll always find code creating many many entities and dealing with core business logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you're writing a repository, your repository methods should be structured around *business processes,* not CRUD methods.
2. Writing Linq instead of these methods is not all that difficult, and you can combine conditions.

   ```
   var result = Cars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ManufacturerID == manufacturerID 
         && x.ModelID == modelID);
   ```

**Further Reading**
[P of EAA: Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)
[The Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Comment: Although I love the simplicity of LINQ, it isn't all that easy to change all the code into queries: Like callbacks which are automatically called by other code to return a list of stuff. Also, can you elaborate on point 1?

Comment: `Although I love the simplicity of LINQ, it isn't all that easy to change all the code into queries: Like callbacks which are automatically called by other code to return a list of stuff.` -- I would need to see an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: `Also, can you elaborate on point 1?` -- See the Further Reading links I posted below my question, but basically your repository methods should be more like `FulfillSomeBusinessProcess()` rather than `GetSomeRecordByID()`.  It's likely that *you already have a data access layer,* so don't duplicate that functionality in your repository.

Comment: Things like callbacks from `.aspx` from our framework's data loading mechanism: `<select DataLoadClass='Entity' DataLoadMethod='LoadLatest' ... />`

Comment: Ah, well you may be stuck with that bit of scaffolding if you want to continue following the pattern set forth by that particular mechanism.

Comment: @wingleader Can that framework's data loading mechanism be changed? If yes, how much?

Comment: @Euphoric pretty much not, but I'm not targeting that framework's use too much, it doesn't make for such a high percentage of the LoadBy methods, its bulk is in classes and C# code

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is good technical solution. I would always recommend a [Query pattern](http://crosscuttingconcerns.com/CommandQuery-Object-pattern), but that just shifts the problem from "add method" to "add class", albeit in [OCP](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf) way.

So only possible option is people solution. If people don't understand LINQ, then teach them. Have a weekly or even daily trainings on how to use LINQ. Motivate them to learn it themselves and try it. Identify people who understand it and who will be ready to help others if they don't understand anything. Do a code review of DB code, so duplicates can be identified. Pick people who will be responsible for DB code and who will roam the codebase, fixing, deduplicating and refactoring code. Motivate people to look for existing solution before they add their own.

Comment: So the bottom line is: It's commonplace, accepted and best practice to sprinkle these LINQ calls?

Comment: @wingleader Yes, basically. LINQ is so far least bad from all the ideas I have. Query objects would be better if your queries were more complex. If it is just filtering by IDs and simple joins, then LINQ is slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use [Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) pattern?

Then you will be able to pass only Specification to a `Repository`'s `loadBySpecification()` method.